# How to add a table in the cover

Tags: tables, titles

I am new to Latex and I start with a default template. But I would like to design a cover like this, but I could not find a way of adding a table in the cover page. (Not in the content). May someone told me how to do it? or any documentation I can refer to ?

The expecting cover page is shown as the screenshot below

[image]

Notes:
Currently what i am starting to use the blank project in overleaf.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{My Proj Name}
\author{My Name}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  "A default template" is very vague - there are many templates that people use for TeX (some worse than others).  Could you [edit] into your post the smallest TeX file that creates your title page?

Comment: @Teepeemm Hi, Thanks for your advice. I've added the code below. Currently it only include `title` , `author` and `date` in the cover page. It should be the simplest one. I am wondering how can I begin to design. eg. add a table below it.

Comment: Instead of `\maketitle` you could use the `titlepage` environment. See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/134144

Comment: `article` will let you put a table after the `\maketitle` command.  If you're aiming for a longer work, then you might want the `book` class, and the `titlepage` environment that leandriis pointed out could be useful.

Comment: You might also look at the efroms package to create editable PDFs.